# Azure Data Factory Stored Procedure Multiple Inputs

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

In my data factory I've got a stored procedure which manipulates 2 tables for a single output. I need to pass 2 sqlWriterTableType but I cant seem to see how this is possible, anyone had experience of doing this ?

```
 "sink": {
                    "type": "SqlSink",
                    "sqlWriterStoredProcedureName": "spDashStat",
                    "sqlWriterTableType": "UserType",
                    "sqlWriterTableType": "StatsType",
                    "writeBatchSize": 0,
                    "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "InputDataset-kpx"
                },
                {
                    "name": "InputDataset-kpx"
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you explained it correctly, you want to call a stored procedure and give parameters to it? That is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-stored-procedure

Remember that its not mandatory for a pipeline to have an input dataset. Use an output dataset to save the output of your stored procedure.

Please give more info for a more detailed answer :)

Cheers!